# jQuery sortable issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a problem while using jQuery sortable. I am using sortable between two unordered lists.
If I have list 1 and list 2, then, after sorting, I want to retain all of the elements in list 2. How can I implement this such that if I perform sorting again, then the list I had before sorting would be still be available? I want to maintain that list.

Comment: What plugin are you using, if any?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is this
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable#method-toArray